# While dragging the point the location co-ordinates are not changing in openlayer map in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller

i have a map in my site , its created using openlayer.when we are editing the route, the movement of the point is not shown in realtime (while holding and dragging the point). Instead, the point location will only be shown after you have dropped the dot. any solution for this please help

Comment: you probably fire on drag event not on click event in jquery

Comment: yeah am fire in drag event but not get realtime location after dropping point only get the location